# AdapterContextMenuInfo is always null

Tags: android

I tried doing this by the book from android dev docs:

```
// this didn't create a menu, i don't know why
//registerForContextMenu(getListView());

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Note>(this, R.layout.selectset_listitem) {
    @Override

    protected View getView(...) {
        ... custom layout ...

        // this creates a menu, but...
        registerForContextMenu(convertView);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And the `onCreateContextMenu` and `onContextItemSelected` almost exactly as in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu.

here is how it looks in the docs (and my code):

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

but this part always gives me a null info:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    ...
}
```

The only thing that is really unique is that i've got a custom layout for list items (i.e. a couple of text fields and an image). Is there something i need to do to be able to get the index of the list item that the context menu was built for?

Comment: You say onCreateContextMenu is "almost" exactly the same, whats the difference? Can you post that method?

Comment: That method IS exactly as in the docs.

Comment: why did you comment out registerForContextMenu()? It doesn't "create" a menu, it only registers your list view to listen for long touch events, and call onCreateContextMenu. If you dont registerForContextMenu, then most likely onCreateContextMenu will not work.

Comment: i commented the first line out because it didn't seem to work. No context menu was created on long taps in the list view. The uncommented call actually does produce a menu.

Comment: Ok now what happens when you debug, and step into onContextItemSelected? Also are you using a custom adapter? If so post the code.

Comment: debug into onContextItemSelected: info is set to null. I updated the question to include my ArrayAdapter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3139/discussion-between-leech-and-jack)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the `registerForContextMenu()` in the activity on the `ListView`, and not on the view items in the adapter.

Comment: recyclerview's don't seem to work that way. any workaround that you know?

Comment: @eipipuz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466877/how-to-create-context-menu-for-recyclerview

Answer (score 4):

`getMenuInfo()` will work on **ListAdapter**, not on views.

But, You can pass additional data with the tag of the view.

in

```
getView: vi.setTag(position) activity.registerForContextMenu(vi);

declare in Activity private int id;

onCreateContextMenu: id = (int) v.getTag();

onContextItemSelected:
```

you can use the id