# ContextMenu with RecyclerView and Cardviews in it

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-recyclerview

I'd like to have a context menu on the cardview items of a recyclerview.

[How to create context menu for RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466877/how-to-create-context-menu-for-recyclerviw/27458518#27458518) did not really provide a solution for that.

I can create a OnClickListener and a OnLongClickListener on the ViewHolder. I can also put in an OnCreateContextMenu, but onCreateContextMenu is never called.

Can anybody provide an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create context menu for RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466877/how-to-create-context-menu-for-recyclerview)

Comment: Can you select the final answer for your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you dont set a *long click* listener the *menu* will open on *long click* event with:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
      implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, View.OnClickListener,
      MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
      itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        MenuItem myActionItem = menu.add("Some menu item");
        myActionItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
      // Menu Item Clicked!
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to set itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener to a regular imageView or textView and NOT itemView? It only works with itemView in my experimentation.

Answer (score 2):

> hello guys,
>   you can't directly implement these method like **onClickListener**, 
>   **OnContextMenuListener** etc. because **RecycleView** extends **android.view.ViewGroup**
>   so we cant directly use these method.
>   we can implement these methods in **ViewHolder** adapter class. 
>   we can use context menu in RecycleView like this way

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnCreateContextMenuListener {
TextView tvTitle;
ImageView ivImage;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        tvTitle =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        v.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);


    }
```

Now we follow the same procedure while implements the context menu.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");    
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Call");//groupId, itemId, order, title   
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "SMS"); 

    }
```

if you get any difficulties ask in comment.

Comment: Definitely, how to show it then? it's not showing by default… ;) (on long click)

Answer (score 1):

I maybe late to the party but I have an working solution. I have made an gist for it.

Add Context Menu to RecyclerView

**ActivityName.java**

```
//Import Statements

public class ActivityName extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_birthdays);


        //Recycle View
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new BirthdaysListAdapter(data, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    }
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
//Import Statements


public class BirthdaysListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BirthdaysListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    static Context ctx;

    private List<typeOfData> Data;


    public BirthdaysListAdapter(List<typeOfData> list, Context context) {
        Data = list;
        this.ctx = context;

    }

    BirthdaysListAdapter() {
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView Birthday;
        public ImageView colorAlphabet;
        public TextView textInImg;


        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            Birthday = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Birthday);
            colorAlphabet = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.colorAlphabet);
            textInImg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textInImg);


            v.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this); //REGISTER ONCREATE MENU LISTENER
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v                         //CREATE MENU BY THIS METHOD
                                        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            new BirthdaysListAdapter().info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
            MenuItem Edit = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Edit");
            MenuItem Delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete");
            Edit.setOnMenuItemClickListener(onEditMenu);
            Delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(onEditMenu);


        }
//ADD AN ONMENUITEM LISTENER TO EXECUTE COMMANDS ONCLICK OF CONTEXT MENU TASK
        private final MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener onEditMenu = new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {


                DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(ctx);
                List<WishMen> data = dbHandler.getWishmen();

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case 1:
                        //Do stuff
                        break;

                    case 2:
                       //Do stuff

                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        };


    }


    public List<ViewBirthdayModel> getData() {
        return Data;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return super.getItemId(position);
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_view_birthdays, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(Data.get(position).getMan().getName());
        holder.Birthday.setText(Data.get(position).getMan().getBday());
        holder.colorAlphabet.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Data.get(position).getColor()));
        holder.textInImg.setText(String.valueOf(Data.get(position).getMan().getName().toUpperCase().charAt(0)));
           }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Data.size();
    }

    private int position;

    public int getPosition() {

        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid manually programatically defining the context menu inside your adapter then you can use a PopupMenu instead and inflate it from a proper menu.xml

This example below does exactly that and allows you to pass in a listener that will receive select and menu item presses back in your Activity or Fragment that setup this RecyclerView in the first place.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<CustomObject> objects;
private OnItemSelectedListener listener;
private final boolean withContextMenu;

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    @BindView(R.id.custom_name)
    TextView name;

    @BindView(R.id.custom_value)
    TextView value;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        if (withContextMenu) {
            view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onCustomerSelected(objects.get(position));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if (listener != null) {
            CustomObject object = objects.get(getAdapterPosition());
            listener.onCustomerMenuAction(object, item);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public CustomerAdapter(List<CustomObject> objects, OnItemSelectedListener listener, boolean withContextMenu) {
    this.listener = listener;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.withContextMenu = withContextMenu;
}

public interface OnItemSelectedListener {

    void onSelected(CustomObject object);

    void onMenuAction(CustomObject object, MenuItem item);
}

@Override
public CustomerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.snippet_custom_object_line, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CustomObject object = objects.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(object.getName());
    holder.value.setText(object.getValue());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return objects.size();
}
}
```

Full gist here
https://gist.github.com/brettwold/45039b7f02ce752ae0d32522a8e2ad9c