# Android: RecyclerView item Contextmenu issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-contextmenu

I am trying to implement a RecyclerView, that each item when clicked, a context menu will pop up.

I have referred the answers/comments from this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466877/how-to-create-context-menu-for-recyclerview) on how to to do what I wanted.

My problem is, I keep getting null by using getMenuInfo() to retrieve info. Ie, When I select an item from the context menu, this is what I get

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'long
>   com.x.lib.RVCoursesContextMenu$RecyclerContextMenuInfo.id' on a null
>   object reference

My code for this is very similar to this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32633023/5417517) .

I have been looking for a solution for this for a very long time, would really appreciate if someone could help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Context cxt;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, int ViewType, Context cnxt) {
        this.cxt = cnxt;
    }
}
```