# Get Position of ContextMenu Selected in RecycleView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, adapter, contextmenu

Normally for `ListViews`, I would do this when I wanted to get the position that the user clicked on a Context Menu.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    position = info.position;
```

However, ever since I switched to a `RecycleView`, I **now get a null pointer** here.

The code above is in my main `Activity` (`Fragment`) while `onCreateContextMenu()` is done in the `adapter` as per the new way.

`ItemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);` is also done in the adapter (specifically the constructor).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There're 3 options:

1. You can pass `getAdapterPosition()` instead of `MenuItem`'s order

   ```
   private class ChipViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
       public ChipViewHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
           menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");
           menu.add(0, ACTION_1_ID, getAdapterPosition(), "action 1");
           menu.add(0, ACTION_2_ID, getAdapterPosition(), "action 2");
       }
   }
   ```

   And then, in `Activity` listen to `onContextItemSelected()` and retrieve position by `getOrder()`

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       int clickedItemPosition = item.getOrder();
       // do something!
       return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
   }
   ```
2. Use custom implementations of RecyclerView like [Teovald/ContextMenuRecyclerView](https://gist.github.com/Teovald/cba0aa150e60b727636d)  one
3. Setting `MenuItem`'s clickListener (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33179957/1658267 ) and handles it there.

Yes, it's very inconvenient API. You can choose the one you like most.

Comment: Option #1 did the trick.  All I had to do was add one line of code (and replace what I had above) in the Activity; everything else was set up.  Thanks again.